# Join Intersecting Date Ranges in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with date ranges in them, that don't necessarily match between the two. I'm hoping to get a result that combines date ranges (and values) between the two tables if they intersect. Here's an example of the data in the tables:

```
Table A                         Table B
+----------+----------+-------+ +----------+----------+-------+
|StartDate |  EndDate | Hours | |StartDate |  EndDate | Hours |
+----------+----------+-------+ +----------+----------+-------+
|11/02/2014|11/06/2014|  38.75| |11/02/2014|11/02/2014|   7.75|
|12/06/2014|12/10/2014|  23.25| |11/03/2014|11/03/2014|   7.75|
                                |11/04/2014|11/04/2014|   7.75|
                                |11/05/2014|11/05/2014|   7.75|
                                |11/06/2014|11/06/2014|   7.75|
                                |12/09/2014|12/15/2014|  15.50|
```

And the result of the query should look like this:

```
Results
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|StartDate |  EndDate |A Hours|B Hours|
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|11/02/2014|11/06/2014|  38.75|  38.75|
|12/06/2014|12/15/2014|  23.25|  15.50|
```

To try to make what I'm doing more clear, here are some more examples:

```
Table A                         Table B
+----------+----------+-------+ +----------+----------+-------+
|StartDate |  EndDate | Hours | |StartDate |  EndDate | Hours |
+----------+----------+-------+ +----------+----------+-------+
|09/01/2014|09/01/2014|   7.75| |09/02/2014|09/02/2014|   7.75|

Results
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|StartDate |  EndDate |A Hours|B Hours|
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|09/01/2014|09/01/2014|   7.75|   Null|
|09/02/2014|09/02/2014|   Null|   7.75|
```

---

```
Table A                         Table B
+----------+----------+-------+ +----------+----------+-------+
|StartDate |  EndDate | Hours | |StartDate |  EndDate | Hours |
+----------+----------+-------+ +----------+----------+-------+
|08/02/2014|08/02/2014|   7.75| |08/01/2014|08/05/2014|  38.75|
|08/05/2014|08/09/2014|  23.25| |08/08/2014|08/08/2014|   7.75|
|          |          |       | |08/15/2014|08/16/2014|  15.50|

Results
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|StartDate |  EndDate |A Hours|B Hours|
+----------+----------+-------+-------+
|08/01/2014|08/09/2014|  31.00|  46.50|
|08/15/2014|08/16/2014|   Null|  15.50|
```

---

Basically what it comes down to is I'm trying to build a detailed comparison of the hours in the two tables for comparable date ranges.

My biggest issue so far has been trying to find a way to group the results for a date range, when the StartDate and EndDate for each record in my results may be from either table A or table B, depending on the situation.

Comment: If you have rows in table B that aren't in table A for 9/1, 9/2 and 9/3, what is the rule to group them?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic appears to be that `B` records get counted if the start date is between the start and end date in `A`.

```
  select A.StartDate, A.EndDate, A.Hours, sum(B.Hours) as bhours
  from A inner join
       B
       on b.startDate >= a.startDate and b.StartDate <= a.endDate
  group by A.StartDate, A.EndDate A.Hours
```

Comment: Thanks,

Sorry, I should have added more detail maybe. I need ALL records to be counted whether there's an intersect or not, and I need the results from the two tables to be combined into a single record if there is an intersecting date range between the two tables, whether it's a combination of one record per table, or a thousand in each. I'll try to update the original question with more details/more extensive examples.

Answer (score 0):

Well there didn't seem to be a simple solution so I ended up coming up with a complicated one, with a query for each possible scenario, combined together with UNIONs.

First I wrote a query that retrieved all the date ranges that matched perfectly between the two tables

Next, since Access doesn't allow FULL OUTER JOINs, I wrote a LEFT OUTER JOIN query and a RIGHT OUTER JOIN query that retrieve all the date ranges from each table that have no intersection whatsoever with the date ranges in the other table. I joined the tables on

```
(a.StartDate BETWEEN b.StartDate
                 AND b.EndDate
 OR a.EndDate BETWEEN b.StartDate
                  AND b.EndDate)
```

then specified only NULL values in the where clause.

Finally, I had to get all the intersecting date ranges and consolidate them if there are multiple ranges that run together, without the benefit of using a recursive CTE. I basically nested five versions of the same subquery together using outer joins and MIN and MAXing the start and end dates to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to use a sub queries to find each segments startDate and endDate.

```
   select segments.startDate as StartDate, 
            segments.endDate as EndDate,
            sum(A.hours) as AHours,
            sum(B.hours) as BHours
            from (
                select startDate, 
                       min(endDate) as endDate
                from (
                      select distinct starts.startDate
                            from (select A.startDate
                                 from A
                                 union all 
                                 select B.startDate
                                 from b) as starts
                            where not exists 
                                  (select 1
                                   from A
                                   where A.startDate < starts.startDate
                                         and starts.startDate <= A.endDate)
                              and not exists 
                                  (select 1
                                   from B
                                   where B.startDate < starts.startDate
                                         and starts.startDate <= B.endDate)
                            ) as segmentStarts
                inner join (
                           select distinct ends.endDate
                           from (select A.endDate
                                 from A
                                 union all 
                                 select B.endDate
                                 from b) as ends
                           where not exists 
                                 (select 1
                                  from A
                                  where A.endDate > ends.endDate
                                        and ends.endDate >= A.startDate)
                                  and not exists 
                                 (select 1
                                  from B
                                  where B.endDate > ends.endDate
                                        and ends.endDate >= B.startDate) 
                            ) as segmentEnds
                on segmentStarts.startDate <= segmentEnds.endDate
                group by segmentStarts.startDate            
                ) as segments
            left join A
            on segments.startDate <= A.endDate
            and A.startDate <= segments.endDate
            left join B
            on segments.startDate <= B.endDate
            and B.startDate <= segments.endDate
            group by segments.startDate, segments.endDate
            order by segments.startDate
```